# Append() not working

Tags: jquery, html

I have the html as:

```
<div class="oneWay examplefooter" style="display: block;">
   <div class="container mobile-row">
      <div class="examplefooter-sum col-lg-1 col-md-1 nopadding ">
         <b>
            <!-- react-text: 6 -->Price<!-- /react-text --><!-- react-text: 7 --> <!-- /react-text --><br><!-- react-text: 9 --> <!-- /react-text --><!-- react-text: 10 -->Summary<!-- /react-text -->
         </b>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-7 col-md-7 col-xs-9 col-lg-offset-2 col-md-offset-2 no-padding-mobile arrow-wrapper">
         <div>
            <div class="examplefooter-totalWrap" id="trip0">
               <!-- react-text: 41 --> <!-- /react-text -->
               <div class="examplefooter-totalWrap_place">
                  <!-- react-text: 43 -->DEL<!-- /react-text --><!-- react-text: 44 --> - <!-- /react-text --><!-- react-text: 45 -->BLR<!-- /react-text -->
               </div>
               <div class="examplefooter-totalWrap_time">
                  <!-- react-text: 47 -->6E<!-- /react-text --><!-- react-text: 48 --> <!-- /react-text --><!-- react-text: 49 --> 133<!-- /react-text -->
                  <span class="time">
                     <!-- react-text: 51 -->05:05<!-- /react-text --><!-- react-text: 52 --> - <!-- /react-text --><!-- react-text: 53 -->07:50<!-- /react-text -->
                  </span>
               </div>
               <div class="examplefooter-totalWrap_price">
                  <div class="triangle-up small"></div>
                  <span>₹&nbsp;2,473</span>
                  <div class="cfd">(Click for details)</div>
               </div>
               <!-- react-empty: 58 -->
            </div>
         </div>
         <div class="examplefooter-totalFare_wrap">
            <div class="examplefooter-totalFare">
               <div class="triangle-up"></div>
               <span id="totalSummary">
                  <!-- react-text: 63 --> <!-- /react-text --><!-- react-text: 64 -->Total<!-- /react-text --><!-- react-text: 65 -->:  &nbsp;<!-- /react-text --><span>₹&nbsp;2,473</span>
               </span>
               <div class="cfd small">(Click for details)</div>
               <!-- react-empty: 68 -->
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-xs-3 nopadding">
         <button class="yelbtn">
            <span>
               <!-- react-text: 35 -->Continue<!-- /react-text --><!-- react-text: 36 --> <!-- /react-text --><i class="fa icon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            </span>
         </button>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

I am using this command :

```
$('<div id="calendar" class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-xs-2 no-padding-returnFlight"><b>+ Add Return Flight</b></div>').appendTo('.col-sm-3.examplefooter-totalFare_wrap');
```

to insert a div after Total Fare but it is not yielding me a desired result.

Comment: Your code is unbelievably hard to read, please clean it up to just the elements we need to see. `col-sm-3.examplefooter-totalFare_wrap` does not exist as a class anywhere in the example you showed, not even `col-sm-3.example` appears.

Comment: I want "+ Add Return Flight" to be added to the right of Total Fare.

Comment: Try `appendTo('.examplefooter-totalFare_wrap')` – if you chain `.class` together without a space, jQuery looks for an element that has all those classes.

Comment: I used that also, but that is appending the div after div class cfd small

Comment: where you want to append your div? after which div

Comment: Create a class just for this purpose.

Comment: @NishantDixit I want to add after class examplefooter-totalFare_wrap.

Comment: @AmbikaTewari what about my answer, Is working or not according to you?

Answer (score 1):

Your appendTo not working because there is no class with name col-sm-3. Use only examplefooter-totalFare_wrap for append.

Try this,

```
$('<div id="calendar" class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-xs-2 no-padding-returnFlight"><b>+ Add Return Flight</b></div>').appendTo('.examplefooter-totalFare_wrap');
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `prependTo` for this

```
 $('<div id="calendar" class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-xs-2 no-padding-returnFlight"><b>+ Add Return Flight</b></div>').prependTo('.examplefooter-totalFare_wrap');
```

Comment: This command also I had tested, as a result class is getting added below TotalFare and not right to it.

Answer (score -1):

Please remove class .col-sm-3 from script

```
  $('<div id="calendar" class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-xs-2 no-padding-returnFlight"><b>+ Add Return Flight</b></div>').appendTo('.examplefooter-totalFare_wrap');
```